# Force removal of External Table in Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have created an external table in my synapse workspace setting a wrong Location.

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nameTable`

I am trying to remove it but I am getting this error:

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: "name_of_host"
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.dropTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:507)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.dropTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:104)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.dropTable(SessionCatalog.scala:671)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DropTableCommand.run(ddl.scala:216)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:202)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:202)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3377)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:90)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:144)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3376)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:202)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:87)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:656)
org.apache.livy.repl.SQLInterpreter.execute(SQLInterpreter.scala:129)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$7.apply(Session.scala:380)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$7.apply(Session.scala:378)
scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.org$apache$livy$repl$Session$$executeCode(Session.scala:378)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(Session.scala:244)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.org$apache$livy$repl$Session$$withRealtimeOutputSupport(Session.scala:518)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$execute$1.apply$mcV$sp(Session.scala:243)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Session.scala:233)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Session.scala:233)
scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have done some tries like:

- Try to alter the location -> `ALTER TABLE nameTable SET LOCATION yyy`
- Rename the table -> `ALTER TABLE nameTable RENAME TO nameTable2`

But I am always getting the same error...

**EDIT**

**I set a HDFS of our on-prem location by accident:**
[image]

**Is there any way to force a rename, a location or a drop of the table from Synapse workspace?
thanks beforehand**

Answer (score 0):

The posted error is not particularly helpful and this may not work. But, you can try dropping the external table:

```
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE { database_name.schema_name.table_name | schema_name.table_name | table_name }
[;]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but is not working this command...